# Infer schema from json string

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this dataframe :

```
cSchema = StructType([StructField("id1", StringType()), StructField("id2", StringType()), StructField("params", StringType())\
                      ,StructField("Col2", IntegerType())])

test_list = [[1, 2, '{"param1": "val1", "param2": "val2"}', 1], [1, 3, '{"param1": "val4", "param2": "val5"}', 3]]

df = spark.createDataFrame(test_list,schema=cSchema) 

+---+---+--------------------+----+
|id1|id2|              params|Col2|
+---+---+--------------------+----+
|  1|  2|{"param1": "val1"...|   1|
|  1|  3|{"param1": "val4"...|   3|
+---+---+--------------------+----+
```

I want to explode params into columns :

```
+---+---+----+------+------+
|id1|id2|Col2|param1|param2|
+---+---+----+------+------+
|  1|  2|   1|  val1|  val2|
|  1|  3|   3|  val4|  val5|
+---+---+----+------+------+
```

So I coded this :

```
schema2 = StructType([StructField("param1", StringType()), StructField("param2", StringType())])

df.withColumn(
  "params", from_json("params", schema2)
).select(
  col('id1'), col('id2'),col('Col2'), col('params.*')
).show()
```

The problem is that `params` schema is dynamic (variable `schema2`), he may change from one execution to another, so I need to infer the schema dynamically (It's ok to have all columns with String Type)... And I can't figure out of a way to do this..

Can anyone help me up with that please ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Pyspark the syntax should be:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
schema = F.schema_of_json(df.select('params').head()[0])

df2 = df.withColumn(
  "params", F.from_json("params", schema)
).select(
  'id1', 'id2', 'Col2', 'params.*'
)

df2.show()
+---+---+----+------+------+
|id1|id2|Col2|param1|param2|
+---+---+----+------+------+
|  1|  2|   1|  val1|  val2|
|  1|  3|   3|  val4|  val5|
+---+---+----+------+------+
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can do it, hope you can change it to python

Get the schema dynamically with `schema_of_json` from the value and use `from_json` to read.

```
val schema = schema_of_json(df.first().getAs[String]("params"))
df.withColumn("params", from_json($"params", schema))
  .select("id1", "id2", "Col2", "params.*")
  .show(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a larger sample of data to compare, you can read the params field into a list, convert that to an RDD, then read using "spark.read.json()"

```
params_list = df.select("params").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
params_rdd = sc.parallelize(params_list)
spark.read.json(params_rdd).schema
```

Caveat here being that you probably don't want to load too much data, as it's all being stuffed into local variables. Try taking the top 1000 or whatever an appropriate sample size may be.